# Сохранение в csv результатов парсинга vk

Tags: python, вконтакте

Всем привет! написала небольшой код по парсингу сообществ вконтакте посредством итерации списка, содержащего id групп, в результате которого получаю город и количество подписчиков, сохраняемых в csv файл (строка в csv выглядит следующим образом: Moscow, 234; столбец:city,value), однако он не сохраняет последующие результаты.
Мне необходимо, чтобы в строке результат был такой:

```
city,value,value,value
Moscow, 234, 587, 321
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать???? Думала сделать цикл, который бы добавлял последующие значения, но из-за недостатка опыта ничего не могу придумать, так как только недавно начала постигать азы программирования.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать, чтобы решить возникшую проблему???

Фрагмент таблицы csv:

```
city,value 
Moscow,586
Kazan,129
Ivanovo,386
Kursk,679
Saratov,231
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавив в таблицу первую колонку с идентификаторами сообществ удалось решить данную проблему.
Методом pivot в pandas можно сгруппировать файл в сводную таблицу, пример:
df2.pivot_table(index="id", columns="city", values="value", aggfunc="first")
где в качестве индекса передаем идентификаторы сообществ, в колонки названия городов, а количество участников - в values.

Comment: **Наталья**, я проголосовал за ваш вопрос и за ответ и повысил вашу репутацию. Если есть возможность, укажите код. Код можно указывать в обратных апострофах ( там где буква ё ). `Вот так`

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно для начала правильно сагрегировать эти данные. Посмотри библиотеку pandas, в нее можно все твои данные загнать как таблицу, потом по каждому городу сложить значения в один список, и потом уже все это в csv перегнать. Простите, что без кода, но это уже решение задачи будет, так не интересно)

Comment: спасибо большое) посредством метода join я смогла их объединить, однако у меня индексы в колонках установлены в разброс, в связи с чем я не могу их объединить в общую таблицу((( можете мне подсказать, пожалуйста, как мне можно обойти это???? строка из получившегося csv файла: `Moscow, 345, Kazan, 453, Saratov, 85` Мне их нужно объединить для того, чтобы получить общую сводную таблицу